# Nvidia CUDA: Profiler indicates memory transfer operations are not performed asynchronously

Tags: cuda

I have profiled my CUDA application and the profiling results are not as I would expect them to be.

[image: CUDA profile]

Here's a summary of how my application works:

- There are 4 streams used
- The CPU loop runs around polling the state of each stream
- If the stream is found to be idle, then a function is called: `launch_job`

This function looks liks this:

```
launch_job(cudaStream_t stream, ...)
{
    cudaMemcpyAsync(..., stream);
    cuda_process_kernel<<<grid, block, 0, stream>>>(...);
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
    if(err) ...
    cudaMemcpyAsync(..., stream);
}
```

For the first block of 4 kernel thread launches seen in the profiler screenshot, the stream is different for each time `launch_job` is called.

However there is no overlapping of the memory transfers or the kernel execution.

I would have expected to see at least one memory transfer overlapped with a kernel function execution, if not both memory transfers. (One is direction H2D the other is direction D2H but that was probably obvious.)

Have I fundamentally misunderstood something about the way in which streams work? Or is there some other reason why my `launch_job` function does not produce parallelized memory transfer and kernel function execution?

Comment: You should provide a [mcve].  A common error here is not using pinned allocations.  And there is generally no need to wait for a stream to be idle before launching work into it, however that is not by itself the source of the issue here.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I am using cudaMallocHost() and cudaFreeHost() which if I understand allocate and free pinned memory respectively?

Comment: You are using a 10 year old mobile GPU with one copy engine. There will never be overlapping two-way memory transfers. The scheduler has dependency checking and it could be that the depth first approach you are using is stopping compute overlap either because of that or just a victim of heuristics, given you are in a situation where the sum of transfer times is very close to the total execution time. As for any more diagnosis, an [MCVE] is really required rather than code snippets and handwaving.

Comment: Please try this: for each stream, do cudaMemcpyAsync(..., stream)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

1. For each stream, do cudaMemcpyAsync(..., stream) to copy H2D.
2. For each stream, launch the kernels on that stream;
3. For each stream, do cudaMemcpyAsync(..., stream) to copy D2H.

Note you are having three for loops here. If your GPU supports, your profiler should show some overlapping among different streams.

Also, if your data is really small, say only 1 MB, you may not see much overlapping, it would be more obvious if you have 100MB data copy on each stream.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. At the moment I'm not sure this is possible. I have a large number of items to process and only a small number of streams. (At the moment I use 4 but I doubt 4 is an improvement over 2.) The kernels use enough grids to keep all stream multiprocessors fully saturated when running a single kernel. Elsewhere in my code I poll the stream to detect when it has become idle and finished working. So I can't think of a way to process many items with a small number of streams in the way you describe.

Comment: By the way the amount of data is something like of order 10 MB.

Comment: You are free to create many number of streams, hundreds if necessary.

Comment: This issue is the number is finite, and this code runs in an "infinite" loop. (Meaning it runs over an input which can be arbitratily long.)

Comment: Since you are using 4 streams already, and must be managing them to reuse them, just do the steps as I suggested for the 4 streams, see what happens. Later you may try more streams to see if it can achieve any more improvement.